# useEffect first render not setting the posts value to 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am making the infinite scroll in react js , but i am having problem setting the posts value whenever i refresh the page the posts length is 0 whereas it should have been 10.

But after the first reload if i don't reload and just change something in code ( lets say add console.log ) and save it then the whole infinite scroll starts working but if i reload then it stops working

Please help.

Feed.js

```
import { Box, CircularProgress, Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import Post from "./Post";
import About from "./About";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { getInfiniteScroll } from "../apis/posts";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Feed = () => {
  //   const posts = useSelector((state) => state.allPosts.posts);

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
  const [isEnd, setIsEnd] = useState(false);

  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
    ref.current?.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    // return () => ref.current?.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [skip]);
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
      const { data, error } = await getInfiniteScroll(skip);

      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }

      if (data?.length === 0) {
        setIsEnd(true);
        return;
      }
      // setPosts(data);
      setPosts([...posts, ...data]);
      console.log(posts.length);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  const handleScroll = (e) => {
    const { offsetHeight, scrollTop, scrollHeight } = e.target;

    if (offsetHeight + scrollTop >= scrollHeight) {
      console.log(posts?.length);
      setSkip(posts?.length);
    }

    console.log("skip : ", skip);
  };

  return (
    <Box flex={4} sx={{ padding: { xs: "0", sm: "0px 20px " } }}>
      <Box
        ref={ref}
        // onScroll={handleScroll}
        sx={{
          width: { xs: "100%", sm: "105% " },
          marginBottom: "50px",
          height: "600px",
          overflow: "scroll",
          overflowX: "hidden",
        }}>
        {posts.length > 0 ? (
          posts.map((post) => <Post key={post._id} {...post} />)
        ) : (
          <Box
            sx={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignSelf: "center",
              marginTop: "200px",
            }}>
            <CircularProgress
              sx={{
                alignSelf: "center",
              }}
            />
          </Box>
        )}
      </Box>

      <Box
        sx={{
          display: { sm: "none", xs: "block" },
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          paddingBottom: "50px",
        }}>
        <About />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Feed;
```

Posts.js

```
import {
  Avatar,
  Card,
  CardActions,
  CardContent,
  CardHeader,
  CardMedia,
  Checkbox,
  IconButton,
} from "@mui/material";

import ShareIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Share";
import MoreVertIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
import Favorite from "@mui/icons-material/Favorite";
import { FavoriteBorder } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import SmartText from "../Helpers/SmartText";
import { capitalize } from "../Helpers/Capitalize";

const Post = ({ _id, desc, title, photo, caption, updatedAt }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <Card sx={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}>
      <CardHeader
        avatar={
          <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: "red" }} aria-label="recipe">
            {Array.from(title)[0]}
          </Avatar>
        }
        action={
          <IconButton aria-label="settings">
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
        title={capitalize(title)}
        subheader={updatedAt}
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("/posts/singlePost/" + _id);
        }}
        sx={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
      />
      <CardMedia component="img" height="20%" image={photo} alt="Paella dish" />
      <CardContent>
        <SmartText text={desc} />
        {/* <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
              {post.desc}
            </Typography> */}
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions disableSpacing>
        <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
          <Checkbox
            icon={<FavoriteBorder />}
            checkedIcon={<Favorite sx={{ color: "red" }} />}
          />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton aria-label="share">
          <ShareIcon />
        </IconButton>
        {/*  <ExpandMore
            expand={expanded}
            aria-expanded={expanded}
            aria-label="show more"
          >
            <ExpandMoreIcon />
          </ExpandMore> */}
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

api/posts.js

```
export const getInfiniteScroll = async (skip) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`/api/posts/infiniteScroll?skip=${skip}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    return await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

backend/postController.js

```
exports.getInfinitePost = async (req, res) => {
  const skip = req.query.skip ? Number(req.query.skip) : 0;

  const DEFAULT_LIMIT = 10;

  try {
    const posts = await Post.find({}).skip(skip).limit(DEFAULT_LIMIT);

    res.status(201).json({ data: posts, success: true });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error });
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: `console.log` after `setState` will never work

Comment: Below `const { data, error } = await getInfiniteScroll(skip);` console log data, is data definitely getting returned?

Comment: data is being returned, but when i set data to posts , the posts shows empty.